# flask-migrate for multi-tanent postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, multi-tenant, flask-migrate

In my flask project I wrote on my **manage.py** file:

```
from app import app, db
from flask_script import Manager, Shell
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db)

manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager.run()
```

I've two models, **user** and **dashboard**. The idea is, in my postgres database `user` table would be in the default `public schema` and after creating a new user I need to create a `private schema` where the dashboard table will be created.

For the default public schema we usually run `python manage.py db migrate`. It'll then create the tables in default public schema. But what should I do in my case? 
First I've to run migrate command to generate the `User` table in public schema. Then after adding a successful row in user table I need to run a script for creating a private schema where a new table `dashboard` will be generated. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'd have to think about how this can be done, not sure SQLAlchemy or the Flask extension provide enough support for this. If you have figured out how to make Flask-SQLAlchemy's binds attach to all your schemas, then Alembic and Flask-Migrate should be able to handle migrations with the multidb support, but my impression is that getting binds set up for all your schemas is going to be tricky.

Comment: @Miguel, I can create a different schema while a new row inserts in my `User` table using `create_schema` from sqlAlchemy. But I'm bit confused how to run the migrations for that newly created schema. Have any clue?